# 3.3: Can cqlsh (externally) access the kube-api proxy on port 9042

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I can hit this via the browser, but I am assuming cqlsh will not like how the data format coming back

8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/cassandra:cql

from a browser:

```
Error: 'malformed HTTP response "\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00"'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.10.76.31:9042/'
```

Comment: cql is defined as port 9042 in the service, I've tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy in an http proxy that terminates the connection from the client, establishes a separate connection to the backend, and then forwards data. It an an http proxy, and it assumes that the backend is serving http, so it won't work with non-http protocols (like cql appears to be). To reach your cassandra instance from outside your cluster you will need to either expose it directly (as a service) or expose a TCP proxying service in front of it.